# Display the minimum number of a value in a column

Tags: sql, db2

I used a select statement to get the count of the list of clubs:

```
SELECT club,COUNT(club) as mycount FROM member GROUP BY club


   CLUB            COUNT      
--------------- -----------

UCLA  Club                 5
George Club                11
```

I need to show the minimum number of the count table:

```
    CLUB            COUNT
--------------- -----------
UCLA Club                  5
```

I used this statement but it only shows the minimum count as 1 column i need the table to look like the one above how can i get the name of the club:

SELECT MIN(mycount) as Count FROM (SELECT club, COUNT(club) mycount FROM member group by club)

I tried doing:

SELECT club, MIN(mycount) as Count FROM (SELECT club, COUNT(club) mycount FROM yrb_member group by club)

but it gives me an error when i put club after select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is a bit longer but off the top of my head:

```
SELECT cl.club, cnt.mincnt FROM
    (SELECT club, COUNT(*) cnt FROM member GROUP BY club) cl,
    (SELECT MIN(cnt) mincnt FROM (SELECT club, COUNT(*) cnt FROM member GROUP BY club)) cnt
WHERE cl.cnt = cnt.mincnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and `fetch first`:

```
SELECT club, COUNT(club) as mycount
FROM member
GROUP BY club
ORDER BY COUNT(club)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

Note:  This returns more than one row, when there are ties.

EDIT:

If you need to handle ties, use `RANK()`:

```
SELECT club, mycount
FROM (SELECT club, COUNT(club) as mycount,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(club) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM member
      GROUP BY club
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: what if there is 2 clubs with the same amount of members and i need to display both?